# SignalFx filter for None

Tags: filter, signalfx

I'm trying to build a detector with signalfx and I want to make a filter query on a data stream that will fetch me metrics with dimension name "foo" and value "baz" but also ones that do not have this dimension at all. I've been trying something like this:

```
    filter('foo', 'baz', None)
    filter('foo', 'baz', '')
```

but it just proudces errors.

Answer (score 1):

Since my dimension value was a flag I just used a workaround and instead of filtering for value true or None I filter for not True like this:

not filter('foo' '1')

and this works since I wanted all items with foo set to '0' or ones that do not have foo at all.